# How to set up Blazor project and Razorpages project in the same solution

Tags: asp.net, razor, blazor

I created ASP.NET Blazor project and RazorPages project in the same solution. How can I integrate these two projects in the same solution?

Comment: Yu added them to the same solution...then your asking how to integrate them into the same solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference using visual studio. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2022#projects-tab)